# How can I send over unique parameters to respective field in sql server db table when logging?

Tags: c#, sql-server, logging, nlog

I finally got logging working and hooked up to my db table. The insert works just fine!

However, the issue I'm coming across is I'm not sure how to setup the unique data I want to pass into the db table. That is, I have some data that I want to set to the correct parameters so it gets sent to the correct field in the db table.

Currently, what gets inserted to my db table is empty fields or default timestamp that I assume is there because I used `${date}` parameter. How can I correct for that?

E.g.

These are defaults NLog uses to send over data:

```
  <parameter name="@Timestamp" layout="${longdate}"/>
  <parameter name="@Loglevel" layout="${level:uppercase=true}"/>
  <parameter name="@Callsite" layout="${callsite:filename=true}"/>
  <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}"/>
```

But I want to setup something like:

```
<parameter name="@FooBar" layout="${FooBar}"/>
<parameter name="@Description" layout="${Description}"/>
```

However, that results in an empty field sent to the db table. How can I pass in FooBar from my code to the db table Foobar field?

Also, I have this scenario with Description where description has three possible formats/types of info that should get passed to it: 
1) Exception 2) custom Info message I write 3) sql commands from inserts
in which one of them get set depending on where I set the Log statement in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can register your own custom layout renderers, before you create your first NLog-logger-object.

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer